# Kohana Modular Extensions possible like Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, kohana

I have used Codeigniter for several years and now use it with Modular Extensions HMVC which allows me to have separate modules with their own controllers, models and views.

I haven't used Kohana before, and am trying to figure out if it is possible to do this type of HMVC with Kohana 3.  I know it uses modules, but I'm not sure if it's modules in this same kind of HMVC context or not?

I basically need to do things where you can basically drop in a module that would have its own controllers, models, views, etc.  Would Kohana work for something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Kohana has a cascading filesystem, you can get more details @ http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files